# Solving second order coupled differential equations in python

Tags: finite-element, pde, python

as I have to design a reactor and therefore have to get its length x, I have to solve the following differential equations:

$$D_{eg}\tfrac{d^2A_g}{dx^2}-u_g\tfrac{dA_g}{dx} = k_la_b\left(\tfrac{A_g}{H_A}-A_l\right)$$
$$\frac{}{}D_{el}\frac{d^2A_l}{dx^2}-u_l \tfrac{dA_l}{dx}+ k_la_b\left(\tfrac{A_g}{H_A}-A_l\right) = (1-\epsilon_B)\eta_ck_2A_sB_s$$
$$D_{el}\frac{d^2B_l}{dx^2}-u_l \tfrac{dB_l}{dx} = (1-\epsilon_B)\eta_cK_2A_sB_s$$

Only $\eta_c$, $A_s$ and $B_s$ are dependent on $A_G,A_L$ and $B_L$ and can be solved by the following circular arguments:
$$\eta_c = \tfrac{3A_sB_s}{\phi_T^2A_gB_l}(\phi_Tcoth(\phi_T)-1)$$
$$A_s = A_g\left ( f\left (1+\frac{\phi_{A,s}^2(\phi_Tcoth(\phi_T)-1)}{\phi_T^2Bi_{A,w}}  \right )^{-1}+(1-f)\left (1+\frac{\phi_{A,s}^2(\phi_Tcoth(\phi_T)-1)}{\phi_T^2Bi_{A,d}}^{-1}\right) \right )$$
$$B_s = B_l\left(1+\frac{\phi_{B,s}^2f(\phi_Tcoth(\phi_T)-1)}{\phi_T^2Bi_{B,w}}\right)^{-1}
$$
$$\phi_T = \phi_{A,s}(1-\tfrac{\phi_{B,s}^2}{3\phi_{A,s}^2}) \quad if \quad \phi_{A,s}\geq \phi_{B,s}$$
$$\phi_T = \phi_{B,s}(1-\tfrac{\phi_{A,s}^2}{3\phi_{B,s}^2}) \quad if \quad \phi_{A,s}\leq \phi_{B,s}$$
$$\phi_{A,s} = r_p\sqrt[2]{\tfrac{\alpha k_fB_s}{D_A}}$$
$$\phi_{B,s} = r_p\sqrt[2]{\tfrac{\alpha k_fA_s}{D_B}}$$

The Biot number is dependet on the length of the catalyst bed and must therefore be considered while integrating. The indexes only denouce the independet parameters that are being used:
$$Bi = \frac{\alpha_{Bi}x}{\lambda_{Bi}}$$

For the fractional wetting of A, this leads to:
$$Bi_{A,w} = \frac{\alpha_{A,w}x}{\lambda_{A,w}}$$

I tried to use the method of lines to linearize the differential equations and solve it stepwise. This leads to:

$$\frac{dA_{g,i}}{dx} = \frac{1}{u_g}\left (  D_{eg}\frac{A_g(y_{i+1},x)-2A_g(y_i,x)+A_g(y_{i-1},x)}{\Delta x^2}-k_la_b\left ( \frac{A_{g,i}}{H_A}-A_{l,i} \right )\right )$$
$$\frac{dA_{l,i}}{dx} = \frac{1}{u_l}\left (  D_{el}\frac{A_l(y_{i+1},x)-2A_l(y_i,x)+A_l(y_{i-1},x)}{\Delta x^2}+k_la_b\left ( \frac{A_{g,i}}{H_A}-A_{l,i} \right )-(1-\epsilon_B)\eta_ck_2A_sB_s\right )$$
$$\frac{dB_{l,i}}{dx} = \frac{1}{u_l}\left (  D_{el}\frac{B_l(y_{i+1},x)-2B_l(y_i,x)+B_l(y_{i-1},x)}{\Delta x^2}+(1-\epsilon_B)\eta_ck_2A_sB_s\right )$$

I now tried to solve it after this process: http://hplgit.github.io/prog4comp/doc/pub/p4c-sphinx-Python/._pylight006.html

I am now completely lost, as you can´t seem to pass several starting conditions into the function, the Biot numbers halt the prozess, as they are dependent on x.
The starting conditions at x=0 are: $A_G = A_{G,start}, A_L = 0, B_L = B_{L,start},A_{L,s} = 0, B_{L,s} = 0$. The concentrations for $A_G$ and $B_L$ can be chosen arbitrarily, at the moment.
My code until now is the following:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
import mpmath

L = 2
N = 1000
x = np.array([0,L])
dx = x[1]-x[0]
D_eg = 2
D_el = 2
k_L = 3
a_B = 2
H_A = 10
u_G = 1
epsilon_B = 1
u_L = 1
K_2 = 20
f = 1
r_p = 1
k_r = 1
D_A = 1
D_B = 1
alpha_A_w = 1
L_B = 1
lambda_A_w = 1
alpha_A_d = 1
lambda_A_d = 1
alpha_B_w = 1
lambda_B_w = 1
length_mesh = 1000
A_G_Start = 10
B_L_Start = 10


A_G = np.zeros(length_mesh)
A_L = np.zeros(length_mesh)
B_L = np.zeros_like(A_G)


def odes(x,A_G, A_L, B_L):
    # print(A_G)

    N = len(A_G) - 1
    gas_A = np.zeros(N + 1)
    liquid_A = np.zeros_like(gas_A)
    liquid_B = np.zeros_like(gas_A)
    A_L_surface = np.zeros_like(gas_A)
    B_L_surface = np.zeros_like(gas_A)
    A_L_surface[0] = 0.001
    B_L_surface[0] = 0.0001
    for i in range(1, N):
        Thiele_A_ = Thiele_A(r_p,k_r,B_L_surface[i-1],D_A)

        Thiele_B_ = Thiele_B(r_p, k_r, A_L_surface[i - 1], D_B)

        Bischoff_ = Bischoff(Thiele_A_,Thiele_B_)

        Biot_A_w = Biot(alpha_A_w,x,lambda_A_w)
        Biot_A_d = Biot(alpha_A_d, x, lambda_A_d)
        Biot_B_w = Biot(alpha_B_w, x, lambda_B_w)
        A_L_surface[i] = A_L_s(Thiele_A_,Bischoff_,Biot_A_w,Biot_A_d,A_G[i-1])
        B_L_surface[i] = B_L_s(Thiele_B_,Bischoff_,Biot_B_w,B_L[i-1])

        eta = eta_c(A_L_surface[i],B_L_surface[i],A_G[i-1],B_L[i-1],Bischoff_)


        gas_A[i] = (D_eg / dx ** 2) * (A_G[i + 1] - 2 * A_G[i] + A_G[i - 1]) - k_L * a_B * (A_G[i] / H_A - A_L[i]) / u_G
        liquid_A[i] = ((D_el / dx ** 2) * (A_L[i + 1] - 2 * A_L[i] + A_L[i - 1]) + k_L * a_B * (
                    gas_A[i] / H_A - A_L[i]) - (1 - epsilon_B) * eta * K_2 * A_L_surface[i] * B_L_surface[i]) / u_L

        liquid_B[i] = ((D_el / dx ** 2) * (B_L[i + 1] - 2 * B_L[i] + B_L[i - 1]) - (
                    1 - epsilon_B) * eta * K_2 * A_L_surface[i] * B_L_surface[i]) / u_L
    return gas_A,liquid_A,liquid_B



def eta_c(A_L_s, B_L_s, A_G, B_L, Bischoff):
    return 3*A_L_s*B_L_s/(Bischoff**2*A_G*B_L)*(Bischoff*mpmath.coth(Bischoff)-1)


def Bischoff(Thiele_A, Thiele_B):
    if Thiele_A > Thiele_B:
        return Thiele_A * (1 - Thiele_B ** 2 / (3 * Thiele_A ** 2))
    elif Thiele_B >= Thiele_A:
        return Thiele_B * (1 - Thiele_A ** 2 / (3 * Thiele_B ** 2))


def Thiele_A(r_p, k_r, B_L_s, D_A):
    return r_p * (k_r * B_L_s / D_A) ** 0.5


def Thiele_B(r_p,k_r, A_L_s, D_B):
    return r_p / f * (k_r * A_L_s / D_B) ** 0.5


def A_L_s(Thiele_A, Bischoff, Biot_A_w, Biot_A_d, A_G):
    print( A_G * (
                f * (1 + (Thiele_A ** 2 * (Bischoff * mpmath.coth(Bischoff) - 1)) / (Bischoff ** 2 * Biot_A_w)) ** -1))
    return A_G * (
                f * (1 + (Thiele_A ** 2 * (Bischoff * mpmath.coth(Bischoff) - 1)) / (Bischoff ** 2 * Biot_A_w)) ** -1 +
                (1 - f) * (1 + (Thiele_A ** 2 * (Bischoff * mpmath.coth(Bischoff) - 1)) / (
                    Bischoff ** 2 * Biot_A_d)) ** -1)


def B_L_s(Thiele_B, Bischoff, Biot_B_w, B_L):
    return B_L * (
            (1 + (Thiele_B ** 2 * (Bischoff * mpmath.coth(Bischoff) - 1)) / (Bischoff ** 2 * Biot_B_w)) ** -1)

def Biot(alpha,L,lambdaa):
    return alpha*L/lambdaa

def ode_FE(f, U_0, dt, T):
    N_t = int(round(float(T)/dt))
    # Ensure that any list/tuple returned from f_ is wrapped as array
    f_ = lambda u, t: np.asarray(f(u, t))
    u = np.zeros((N_t+1, len(U_0)))
    t = np.linspace(0, N_t*dt, len(u))
    u[0] = U_0
    for n in range(N_t):
        u[n+1] = u[n] + dt*f_(u[n], t[n])
    return u, t

U0_AG = np.zeros(N+1)
U0_AL = np.zeros(N+1)
U0_BL = np.zeros(N+1)
A_G[0] = A_G_Start
A_L[0] = 0
B_L[0] = B_L_Start


x,A_G,A_L,B_L = ode_FE(odes,[A_G,A_L],dt,T=1.2)
```

I would be incredibly happy and thankful, if you could help me.

Comment: You should start slower, implement the ODE for circular motion, some predator-prey model, gravity like sun-earth-moon. These are all simple enough, you can find code examples here, on stackoverflow and on math.SE (some [links here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4176684/how-to-implement-a-runge-kutta-method-rk4-for-a-second-order-differential-equa)). If you are then sure in the structure of a FE or RK2/3/4 integration and the interfaces for the scipy.integrate solvers, then you can switch to integrating such a highly structured ODE system.

Comment: On top of what LutzLehmann mentioned, it is not clear to me how to help you. What is the problem that you are having, what have you tried?

Comment: 1. 
- "As I have to design a reactor and therefore have to get its length x, I have to   solve the following differential equations"                                        - I am now completely lost, as you can´t seem to pass several starting conditions into the function, the Biot numbers halt the prozess, as they are dependent on x. The starting conditions at x=0 are: AG=AG,start,AL=0,BL=BL,start,AL,s=0,BL,s=0. The concentrations for AG and BL can be chosen arbitrarily, at the moment.                                         2. My code until now is the following....